# enabling Robotium in Android

Tags: android, gradle, robotium

I recently decided to switch from Eclipse to Android Studio. While i was able to import my android project, i keep having problems setting up and transfering my unit tests. For testing purposes i made a directory in src folder (java folder and test package). For enabling robotium i followed another stack topic by adding `androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.2.1'`. Eventually i added my test java file from Eclipse. And when i try to run tests, i keep getting "Cannot resolve symbol Solo".

I have little understanding about how AS and gradle works, so probably i am missing something else.
The contents of my build.gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.colormindapps.work_rest__scheduler"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
        testApplicationId "com.colormindapps.work_rest__scheduler.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/tests/java']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.+'

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to make it work is to install Robotium Recorder for Android Studio. After you record a test you can see how Robotium Recorder sets up the gradle files etc.

http://robotium.com/pages/installation-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

You must use separate source set for you android-specific tests, i.e.:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    }
    androidTest {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/tests/java']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.5.4' which resolve all test cases issues